# Ruby on Rails - Get user email from database in a Rake Task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, rake-task

I have that Mailer method and a Rake task to later scheduled with Cron Job and automate with Gem Whenever for send a email to a users:

```
# Mailer:

class MailCourseWarnMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def course_available(user)
    @user = user
    mail(to: @user.email, subject: "Curso disponível")    # ... email sending logic goes here
  end
end

# Task
require 'rake'
desc 'send digest email'
task :send_warn_course, [:user_email] => :environment do |t, args|
  user = MailCourseWarn.find_by_email args[:user_email]
  MailCourseWarnMailer.course_available(user).deliver!
end

# Model 
class MailCourseWarn < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :course

  validates :name, :email, presence: true

end
```

I am currently run the task like this: `rake send_warn_course['user@email.com']` but I need that this be automatic, in a way that when run rake send_warn_course the Rake Task send to all of users in my DB.

Any ideas How can I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the user(s) that need the email and iterate over them. Surely you're indicating which users need the email in the database somehow, so you'll just want to query all those user records, iterate over them, and then send the email.

```
task :send_warn_course, [:user_email] => :environment do |t, args|
  MailCourseWarn.where(needs_warned: true).each do |user|
    MailCourseWarnMailer.course_available(user).deliver!
  end
end
```

Comment: I would remove the `:user_email` parameter is not needed anymore.